# Could not add new app to iTunes-Myapp

Tags: ios

I am trying to add a new app to myapp section in iTunes. Previously every app I have added have been added successfully. But after the latest modification of the iTunes, I am being unable to add the new app. I have added the name,company name, bundle id, sku, version correctly.
But still I am getting the following error:

**Your app information could not be saved. The information for at least one field is missing or is in the wrong format.**

Please let me know if any of you have resolved this problem.

Comment: you should provide some screenshots of the problem. Already have submitted two new apps in new interface, and there were not any problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and tried alternate values for each field. The form validated when I chose a company name with 2 words. It may be that iTunes is looking for the liability modifiers associated with a company e.g "Company Ltd". Worth a shot.